# Why does Rails runner shebang not work on Debian but work on OS X?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shebang

I have a Rails script that I run on both OS X Lion and Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 (wheezy).  It's down to a simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /opt/thermyos.com/server/script/rails runner
ENV.each do |k, v|
  puts "#{k} = #{v}"
end
```

The issue is the /usr/bin/env.  This script as shown will not run on Debian, producing the error `/usr/bin/env: /opt/thermyos.com/server/script/rails runner: No such file or directory`.  On OS X it works fine, writing the Rails environment.  But if I remove the /usr/bin/env so the shebang is `#!/opt/thermyos.com/server/script/rails runner` then it works fine on Debian but not on OS X (Rails is not loaded and so every line fails).  It doesn't matter where I launch the script from or whether I use a relative or absolute path.  The printed environments are nearly identical.  Why the failure on Debian, as it's exactly the shebang output by just running `rails runner`?  FWIW, /opt/thermyos.com/ is exported from Debian and NFS-mounted on OS X.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the shebang operation on Linux doesn't split arguments.

As a result, env is looking for a file with spaces in the name i.e. trying to execute `/opt/thermyos.com/server/script/rails runner` with no arguments.

On OS X, the situation differs. The shebang in OS X does split arguments and therefore env executes the file at `/opt/thermyos.com/server/script/rails` with the argument `runner`.

One workaround is to use a wrapper script e.g. the form

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /path/to/script/rails runner /path/to/your_script.rb
```

should work on either OS. (whether the paths are hard-coded, computed, relative, or locally configured depends on your circumstances)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in one file without using a wrapper.

Make a ruby script and put this at the top:

```
exec("/path/to/script/rails","runner",$0,*ARGV) unless defined?(Rails)
```

Or:

```
exec("/usr/bin/env","rails","runner",$0,*ARGV) unless defined?(Rails)
```

More info and a more ridiculous solution available at:

http://solutions.davesource.com/20161216.Shebang-That-Calls-Ruby-Rails-Script-With-Arguments.html

Answer (score 0):

First, does `env` live in a different path on your Debian box? `which env` will tell you.

Secondly, I'm somewhat confused. It sounds like you're mounting a file server on both your OS X and your Debian machine, and trying to run the Ruby executable on that server in both environments. Pretty sure that will not work - you need Ruby complied for your Debian/Linux system and another Ruby compiled for your OS X system.

Maybe I'm misreading, but thought I'd point that out.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I verified that env is in /usr/bin on both platforms.  There's no file server.  The /opt/thermyos.com/ directory is exported from Debian and mounted on OS X and each platform uses rvm to manage its native Rails.   The executables live in different locations, but I expect env to provide the appropriate paths.  I appreciate whatever you can point out to look for, as I've got nothing.